# Difference between \Magento\Framework\App\Shell vs \Magento\Framework\Shell

Tags: magento2, cron, shell

I was trying to execute shell commands from the Magento application and came across the following class class in the framework

`\Magento\Framework\App\Shell` and `\Magento\Framework\Shell`

Not sure between the difference between the two.

Wanted to know if the classes serve the same purpose or have there own set of use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library with object-oriented interface for generation of shell commands. Provides an indirection layer that can be used for customizing or testing (mocking) `exec()` function.

Implements placeholders for command arguments that are automatically escaped in format appropriate to the current OS. Provides ability for logging/capturing the commands and their output.

Comment: Hey @anas-mansuri, I do understand the purpose of the having a class, don't understand why there are 2 of them